# Netcdf generator python

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

the following code takes temperature data from a nomad server and generates a netcdf file with this data in three dimensions (time, latitude and longitude). It works fine except when xmin <0 and xmax> 0. In this case report error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./make_basic.py", line 79,
>   in 
>       tmpvar[:]=var[0,xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax]   File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 3695, in
>   netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.**getitem** (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:38039)
>   File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 4376, in
>   netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._get (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:47286)
>   RuntimeError: NetCDF: DAP server error

If xmin <0 and xmax <0, or both are greater than zero, it works correctly. Does anyone know what may be failing? It is important to do for example a netcdf of europe from negative to positive coordinates, since 0 is the meridian of Greenwich.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import sys

dods='http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/gfs_0p25_1hr/gfs20170928/gfs_0p25_1hr_00z'
newfile='sdffile.nc'

xmin=-100
xmax=100
ymin=448
ymax=649

cdata=netCDF4.Dataset(dods,'r')

lon=cdata.variables['lon']
lat=cdata.variables['lat']
time=cdata.variables['time']
var=cdata.variables['tmp2m']

## Set Some Globals
newdata=netCDF4.Dataset(newfile,'w')
newdata.title="GFS"
newdata.Conventions="COARDS"
newdata.dataType='Grid'
newdata.history='Example Self Describing NetCDF File From GrADS-Aholic'

newdata.createDimension('lat', len(lat[ymin:ymax]))
newdata.createDimension('lon', len(lon[xmin:xmax]))
newdata.createDimension('time', 1)

### Create dimensional variables: ###
### For dimension variables, COARDS attributs are required for GrADS self describing

### Do latitude (f8 = float64):
latvar=newdata.createVariable('lat','f8',('lat'))
latvar.grads_dim='y'
latvar.grads_mapping='linear'
latvar.grads_size=len(lat[ymin:ymax])
latvar.units='degrees_north'
latvar.long_name='latitude'
latvar.minimum=str(lat[ymin])
latvar.maximum=str(lat[ymax])
latvar.resolution='0.25'
latvar[:]=lat[ymin:ymax]

### Do longitude (f8 = float64):
lonvar=newdata.createVariable('lon','f8',('lon'))
lonvar.grads_dim='x'
lonvar.grads_mapping='linear'
lonvar.grads_size=len(lon[xmin:xmax])
lonvar.units='degrees_east'
lonvar.long_name='longitude'
lonvar.minimum=str(lon[xmin])
lonvar.maximum=str(lon[xmax])
lonvar.resolution='0.25'
lonvar[:]=lon[xmin:xmax]

### Do Time (f8 = float64):
### Added grads_min and grads_step to attributes
timevar=newdata.createVariable('time','f8',('time'))
timevar.grads_dim='t'
timevar.grads_mapping='linear'
timevar.grads_size=1
timevar.units='days since 1-1-1 00:00:0.0'
timevar.grads_min='00z30dec2015'
timevar.grads_step='3hr'
timevar.long_name='time'
timevar.minimum='00z30dec2015'
timevar.maximum='00z31dec2015'
timevar.resolution='0.125'
timevar[:]=time[0]

### Now that dimensional variables are finished, the other variables are written
### 2 meter temperature (f4=float32) ###
tmpvar=newdata.createVariable('TMP','f4',('time','lat','lon'),fill_value=9.999E20)
tmpvar.long_name='2 Meter Temperature'
tmpvar.units='K'
tmpvar[:]=var[0,xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax]
print 'Done with 2 meter Temperature!'

newdata.close()

cdata.close()

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this works correctly when creating all your instances?  I've been looking at your code and I have my doubts it's behaving as you intend.

```
#! /usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                            

# Python package imports
import sys

# Third party imports
import netCDF4
import numpy as np

# Package imports

# code

dods=('http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/gfs_0p25_1hr/'                     
      'gfs20180221/gfs_0p25_1hr_00z')                                           

# I changed the link because the link below is unavailable                      

# dods=('http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/gfs_0p25_1hr/'                   

#       'gfs20170928/gfs_0p25_1hr_00z')   
newfile='sdffile.nc'

xmin=-100
xmax=100
ymin=448
ymax=649

cdata=netCDF4.Dataset(dods,'r')

lon=cdata.variables['lon']
lat=cdata.variables['lat']
time=cdata.variables['time']
var=cdata.variables['tmp2m']
print(lon)
print(var)
## Set Some Globals
newdata=netCDF4.Dataset(newfile,'w')
newdata.title="GFS"
newdata.Conventions="COARDS"
newdata.dataType='Grid'
newdata.history='Example Self Describing NetCDF File From GrADS-Aholic'

print(len(lat[ymin:ymax]))
print(len(lon[xmin:xmax]))

newdata.createDimension('lat', len(lat[ymin:ymax]))  # this is a potential problem
newdata.createDimension('lon', len(lon[xmin:xmax]))  # this is a potential problem
newdata.createDimension('time', 1)

print(newdata.dimensions['lat'])
print(newdata.dimensions['lon'])
cdata.close()
sys.exit()
```

This produces the following output:

```
$ python stackoverflow.py 
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 lon(lon)
    grads_dim: x
    grads_mapping: linear
    grads_size: 1440
    units: degrees_east
    long_name: longitude
    minimum: 0.0
    maximum: 359.75
    resolution: 0.25
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (1440,)
filling off

<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 tmp2m(time, lat, lon)
    _FillValue: 9.999e+20
    missing_value: 9.999e+20
    long_name: ** 2 m above ground temperature [k] 
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (121, 721, 1440)
filling off

201  # the length of your 'lat' dimension
0    # the length of your 'lon' dimension, making it unlimited
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lat', size = 201

<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'> (unlimited): name = 'lon', size = 0
```

In python, `array[start:end]` typically selects the range from the array you want.  Arrays start at 0 and increment by one.  When you're mixing positive and negative numbers to slice an array, it doesn't work the same as on a number line.  A negative number means count left from the end of the array.  A positive number means count right from the beginning of the array.  You are starting further into the array than you are ending.  This is creating a zero length array and telling netCDF to create an unlimited variable.  I don't think this is what you want to do.  To illustrate this on a smaller scale, we will use an array of size 5.

```
xmin = -2  
xmax = 2

lon = np.arange(5)  # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
lon[2:-2]  # produces a result because you're increasing the array index.
           # starting at 2 and moving forward to 2 before the end of the array
           # this selects item 2 because it starts at lon[2] which is 2 and ends
           # at lon at 2 because it is 2 spaces from the end of the array
lon[-2:-1]  # this works because you're starting two away from the end and moving
            # to one index away from the end of the array.  The starting index
            # is still smaller than the ending index
lon[-2:2]   # will not work because you are telling the array to start two places
            # from the end of the array and move to the second spot in the array.
            # the array is not a queue.  It will not hit the tail and start over.
            #  It will move to the second spot from the end of the array and return
            # an empty array because it is already past the end position you specified.
            # this returns array([], dtype=int64).  calling len() on this gives 0
```